# Date substraction returning odd value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to allow the destruction of a record only if this record has been created within the last 30 minutes.

Then I retrieve the `created_at` value of my record (date2) and check against `Time.now` (date1) :

```
date1 = 2016-09-21 19:44:52 +0200
date2 = 2016-09-21 17:23:16 UTC
```

then I just substract the two :

```
(date1-date2).minutes.to_i
```

But the result returned is in the 10s of thousands (something like 97000) and increasing very fast when i refresh..(as `Time.now` changes)  **whereas we should only get 141 minutes** as per above example values

Comment: Here's a hint: `30.minutes.to_i` returns `1800`. (remove `to_i` to find the explanation)

Comment: well `to_i` doesnt do much when i remove it. It erases the decimal part of the difference between the two dates. Though the `minutes` seems to be a valid Ruby method but not related to Time, that's why I guess my result is all messed up. I have found `to_f` which  instead returns the number of seconds I can then divide by 60 : `(date1-date2).to_f/60` . I still have a discrepancy but I guess it's because of one being UTC and the other +0200. will try to fix it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.minutes` is what makes the thing don't work. Remove it and it should work.
If you want to find the gap in minutes between to date you just have to substract them, divide the result per 60 and round it.

```
((date1 - date2) / 60).round
```

Hope it helped, happy ruby coding!

Comment: thanks you are correct. I applied  `to_f` to the result but redondant. Actually I had a time zone discrepancy too. the following works : `(date1.utc-date2.utc)/60`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the local time (`time1`) to UTC time, or UTC time (`time2`) to local time.

```
require 'time'

time1 = Time.parse('2016-09-21 19:44:52 +0200')
  #=> 2016-09-21 19:44:52 +0200 
time2 = Time.parse('2016-09-21 17:23:16 UTC')
  #=> 2016-09-21 17:23:16 UTC 

(time1.utc - time2)/60
  #=> 21.6
```

Comment: indeed. this is the answer I use. I leave the right answer with Gregory as it is very close and mark yours as useful. tks

Comment: I thought `time1` was a better name for a `Time` object than `date1`. :-)

Comment: well I use neither. in my code, one is a raw `Time.now.utc` and the other is a call to created_at on the very record. Tried to make it simple ^^